# C#: Object Array with Constructor parameter

Tags: c#, object

I have a class `Measurement`.

I have a constructor inside this class. as:

```
class Measurement
    {
      public Measurement(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            ....
        }
}
```

How can I create an Array of 8 Objects with the MainWindow Parameter?

Like somewhere in my code:

```
Measurement[] measurements= new Measurement[8](mainWin);
```

Comment: And what do you expect "new Measurement[8](mainWin); " would do?

Comment: I have 8 drawings with different properties

Answer (score 15):

Do you want an array with a single reference 8 times, or 8 *separate* `Measurement` objects?

For the first:

```
var measurements = Enumerable.Repeat(new Measurement(mainWin), 8).ToArray();
```

For the second:

```
var measurements = Enumerable.Range(0, 8)
                             .Select(_ => new Measurement(mainWin))
                             .ToArray();
```

(Or just create an array without initializing the elements, then populate it with a loop, of course. It's a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: Well done for pointing out the behaviors of both methods, but in what situation might one want an array of 8 (or any number) references to the same object? Or do you mean that the `MainWindow` is the object that is referenced multiple times? and there is infact 8 seperate instances of `Measurement`?

Comment: @BhushanFirake It's the name of the parameter for the anonymous method; in this case the number from the call to `Range`.  Using `_` as the name of a variable that is unused is a common convention.

Comment: I've never seen a `Select` overload that accepts a 2nd parameter.  What does the `, 8` do?

Comment: @Brandon I think that's just an error in his code from copy paste.

Comment: @Servy I have never seen it before...thankx for adding to my knowledge..:)

Comment: @Brandon: Doh - just a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: @musefan: Imagine an immutable type for the state of a space on a game board. Given immutability, it's fine to populate the whole board with the same reference to the initial state - then any changes to the state of the board would change the array element to refer to the new state. It's relatively rare, but I wanted to draw attention to the two different potential meanings.

Comment: You could also `Enumerable.Repeat(mainWin, 8).Select(mw => new Measurement(mw)).ToArray();`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use LINQ:

```
var measurements = Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(i => new Measurement(mainWin)).ToArray();
```

A second way is to use the array initializer syntax:

```
var measurements = new[] {
    new Measurements(mainWin), new Measurements(mainWin), 
    new Measurements(mainWin), new Measurements(mainWin), 
    new Measurements(mainWin), new Measurements(mainWin), 
    new Measurements(mainWin), new Measurements(mainWin)
};
```

Comment: @user2261524 If it is the perfect answer as you say, you should mark it as "correct".

Answer (score 3):

There is this way (by using [Enumerable.Repeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx)) :

```
var measurements = Enumerable.Repeat(new Measurement(mainWin), 8).ToArray();
```

Quote :

> Generates a sequence that contains one repeated value.

Comment: This will only create 1 Measurement object, not 8.  That's probably not desirable.

Comment: Yes it will. But since all have already answered the correct way in filling the array i felt like adding this aswell. Have added a quote from the link included in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Since several correct methods have been added you decided to add an incorrect method?  That doesn't really make sense.  Note that it may not be obvious to all readers that this is repeating a reference to the object, and not repeating a call to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
Measurement[] measurements= new Measurement[8];

for(int i = 0; i < measurements.Length; i++)
{
   measurements[i] = new Measurement(mainWin);
}
```